# Java Runtime Environment fatal error - SIGILL (0x4)

Tags: java, processing

I am getting this error when running Java (via Processing) and Java crashes. Not clear on what the error is - it seems generic, searches turn up different contexts and answers. Anyone know what the issue might be?

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGILL (0x4) at pc=0x00007fff2ba6bb1b, pid=583, tid=0x0000000000001803
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_202-b08) (build 1.8.0_202-b08)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.202-b08 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [CoreFoundation+0xab1b]  CFEqual+0x293
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
```

The full error written to the log file is here https://pastebin.com/fZT9Xyje.

This is the code I'm using in Processing:

```
void settings()
{
 size(500, 500, P3D); //in 3+
}

void setup() {
  size(500,500,P3D); //in 2+
  background(0);
}

void draw() {

}
```

OSX 10.14.6, Radeon Pro 555X 4 GB Intel UHD Graphics 630 1536 MB, Java version 8 build 261  (build 1.8.0_261-b12)

Comment: Ultimately this is a crash in the native part of Java.  Are you using any JNI or other native code?

Comment: I've added the Processing code to the post above, it's the P3D in `size(500, 500, P3D);` that's causing the crash. This is all I'm not using anything else.

Comment: @garrettlynchirl which version of Processing are you running ? Overall it looks like a Java/OpenGL(JOGL) error talking to the video driver, but it's hard to pin point exactly. I'm on OSX 10.11 with a different GPU so might not able to replicate your issue, but in the past when I had crashes like this I've noticed files like `hs_err_pid3161.log` produced in the home folder (where `pid####`) was the process ID of the Processing sketch that crashed. If such a log is still produced (in your case something like `~/hs_err_pid583.log`) you should post it. It contains the OS/C++ side of the crash.

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza I've tried it in every version of Processing 3+, including Processing 3.0b5  as the post here - https://github.com/processing/processing/issues/4104 says that's a workaround. I've also tried the ne Processing 4 alpha - same result on all versions. Yes log files are being written. I've put the full log file output here - https://pastebin.com/fZT9Xyje.

Comment: Not an expert, but that rough looks like `getMonitorMode0()` (Java OpenGL c++ bindings (JOGL)) crash as oon as soon as Processing tries to setup an OpenGL surface to render (something with getting indices). Is your mac using the older Intel CPU or the newer M1 ? (Maybe there's something with the bindings not having the c++ native libraries recompiled for M1 ?) ? A very slim chance, but does adding an external display change anything ? Although not a solution per-se, but if you need a generative 3D piece on your mac it might be worth trying [OpenFrameworks](https://openframeworks.cc/download/).

Comment: ...it's c++ / setup isn't as simple as Processing, but once you have the empty example compiled you'll find a lot of familiar things like `setup()` / `draw()` / etc.  Alternatively you can also try [p5.js `WEBGL` renderer](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Getting-started-with-WebGL-in-p5): though the full Processing 3D featureset may not be supported, there's a lot there and even a few extras Processing doesn't have (e.g. orbit camera, more primitives, etc.)

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza I have OpenFramworks pencilled in for some teaching at a later point but this is for first years so needs to be on the level of Processing or something Javascript based as it is their first touch with code. Yes you are right, it's an issue with an external monitor resolution. I managed to pin down the issue this morning, anything above 1920 x 1200 seems to cause it. I've opened an issue on GitHub for this here - https://github.com/processing/processing/issues/6195.

Comment: It is a pretty gnarly bug by the looks of it. One other thing I remember having issue in the past with is video converters: spotted this in your github issue: (MacBook Thunderbolt 3 > HDMI adaptor > HDMI to DVI adaptor > Monitor DVI).) if you have access to an HDMI monitor or anything that can be easily plugged in directly I'd also test that. (I experienced issues with displays loosing the signal after resolution changes when using DisplayPort to DVI > DVI to HDMI and "got around" by finding a monitor with a DisplayPort connection and simply going DisplayPort to DisplayPort).

Comment: Hopefully p5.js WEBGL has enough of what you need 